# What is "js-gps -track" as class name in almost every button and element in Stack Overflow?

Tags: html

I was exploring stack over flow's `HTML` and `CSS` then I noticed that **JavaScript-GPS-track** class is almost in every element.

When user click on upvote button then it also have that class. Even on footer links.

So, What is it exactly? Does it locate user's location or does it locate user's IP address?

If it does locate, then why using `onClick` class name?

Image of one of the class:
[image: Image of one of the class]

Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Searching through the javascript source code in the developer tools, all it appears to be related to is gathering statistics about which links are clicked. Most likely `gps` is just an acronym that StackExchange made up, short for "gather page statistics" or something like that.

Comment: @alter_igel, What is the main use of putting `js-gps-track` ("gather page statistics" as you point out) class on **Bookmark** button, Does it prove anything of gathering statistics of that button, Almost like `"Guys Let's check , how many times a bookmarks button clicked"` ?

Comment: You'd be surprised how much the folks at the top like to watch statistics like that. Fortunately a lot of it is announced publicly: check out, for example, the `[a-b-testing]` tag on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-b-testing